# Fastboot doesn't recognize OnePlus3 although adb does

Tags: rooting, fastboot, oneplus-3

When trying to root my OnePlus3 I ran into the issue that when running `fastboot devices` my output is blank. Some people said that even while it returns a blank output other commands should still work but `fastboot oem unlock` just says it's waiting for my device without ever proceeding. Also in my device manager I can see ´Kedacom USB device > Android Bootloader Interface´ and I think that might be the problem which I also found in "[Kedacom USB Device doesnt work with fastboot Nexus 5x](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/161420/kedacom-usb-device-doesnt-work-with-fastboot-nexus-5x)". However no solution is provided here.

When I'm using `adb devices` after a normal boot it returns `List of devices attached` `2a04cf0c        device` and in my device manager I can also see `USB devices > ADB interface`

Comment: How do you get to the bootloader mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with my OnePlus One. Since, I was already on a Linux system, USB drivers weren't the issue. All I had to do is to use prefix the `fastboot` command with a `sudo` as `sudo fastboot oem unlock`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a OnePlus One. The problem is that Windows 10 does not let you install the right driver, assuming you are using Windows 10.

I was able to solve it by using a Windows 7 machine instead.

Another solution I found, but haven't tried, is to disable [driver verification](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/). 
This should allow you to install the right drivers, even if the verification fails. However, I do not recommend this as it makes your computer vulnerable to bogus drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Fastboot and ADB requires different drivers. The driver that oneplus provides with the phone doesn't include the Fastboot one. Try to find the fastboot driver, or, if you can't find it, perform your operations on Linux or macOS. These two OSes doesn't require any drivers for using fastboot and adb.